# Hi, How to do get mysql script convert mssql script?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, converters

I would like to convert this query from MySQL to MSSQL, can you please assist? Thanks For you reply,

```
view_taksitmus  CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_taksitmus` 

AS (select `t`.`taksitid` AS `taksitid`,`t`.`policeid` AS `policeid`,`t`.`vade` AS `vade`,
`t`.`tutar` AS `tutar`,
if(isnull(sum(`tm`.`tutar`)),0,sum(`tm`.`tutar`)) AS `odenen`,
if(isnull(sum(`tm`.`tutar`)),`t`.`tutar`,(`t`.`tutar` - sum(`tm`.`tutar`))) AS `kalan`,
`p`.`policeno` AS `policeno`,`p`.`zeyilno` AS `zeyilno`,`p`.`yenilemeno` AS `yenilemeno`,`p`.`plaka` AS `plaka`,`p`.`doviz` AS `doviz`,`p`.`kur` AS `kur` from ((`ins_taksitmus` `t` left join `ins_takmak` `tm` on((`t`.`taksitid` = `tm`.`taksitid`))) left join `view_police` `p` on((`t`.`policeid` = `p`.`policeid`))))
```

Comment: First, re-format your question to something more readable. Second, SQL is SQL (quite similar across different DBMSs), so you should be able to perform such conversion if you dedicate a little effort.

Comment: Salam bhai.. please ask question properly. this link may help you. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e568439-c4b3-4275-a9bb-8539d19f6f4e/how-to-execute-mysql-script-in-sql-server?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
CREATE VIEW view_taksitmus 
AS 
select t.taksitid AS taksitid
      ,t.policeid AS policeid
      ,t.vade AS vade
      ,t.tutar AS tutar
      ,CASE WHEN sum(tm.tutar) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sum(tm.tutar) END AS odenen
      ,CASE WHEN sum(tm.tutar) IS NULL THEN t.tutar ELSE (t.tutar - sum(tm.tutar)) END AS kalan
      ,p.policeno AS policeno
      ,p.zeyilno AS zeyilno
      ,p.yenilemeno AS yenilemeno
      ,p.plaka AS plaka
      ,p.doviz AS doviz
      ,p.kur AS kur 
from ins_taksitmus t 
left join ins_takmak tm on t.taksitid = tm.taksitid
left join view_police p ont.policeid = p.policeid
```

Comment: Super Thank You I'm grateful you.